# Why does the rooster symbolise France?

Tags: france, national-symbols

The [Gallic Rooster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallic_rooster) is widely used as a symbol of France. However, there are a number of conflicting sources on how it originated.

The [French embassy in the USA states](http://franceintheus.org/spip.php?article604) that the rooster originated from a wordplay for "Gaul" and "rooster" in Latin:

> It is the symbol of the French people because of the play on words of
>   the Latin gallus meaning Gaul and gallus meaning coq, or rooster.

However, the [source cited by Wikipedia (in French)](http://franceintheus.org/spip.php?article604) further expands on this claim:

> ... association with France dates back from the Middle Age and is due
>   to the play on words in Latin between Gallus, meaning an inhabitant of
>   Gaul, and gallus, meaning rooster, or cockerel. Its use, by the
>   enemies of France, dates to this period, originally a pun to make fun
>   of the French, the association between the rooster and the
>   Gauls/French was developed by the kings of France for the strong
>   Christian symbol that the rooster represents : prior to being
>   arrested, Jesus predicted that Peter would deny him three times before
>   the rooster crowed on the following morning. At the rooster's crowing,
>   Peter remembered Jesus's words.

The [French governmental website](http://www.gouvernement.fr/en/the-gallic-rooster) doesn't state a definitive origin for the symbol, but notes the wordplay and states that the rooster was used as a religious symbol, as well as a symbol of opposition to Germany's eagle:

> In the Middle Ages, the Gallic Rooster was widely used as a religious
>   symbol, the sign of hope and faith. It was during the Renaissance that
>   the rooster began to be associated with the emerging French nation. 
>   ...
>
> During the First World War, rising patriotic feeling made the Gallic
>   rooster the symbol of France’s resistance and bravery in the face of
>   the Prussian eagle. Use of this Manichean representation, in
>   particular by political cartoonists, gained ground, and the rooster
>   became the symbol of a France sprung from peasant origins, proud,
>   opinionated, courageous and prolific.

A [Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/polandball/comments/3iufhi/spirit_animals/cujuuxu) (which started off this search) claims the symbol originated because the rooster is seen as gallant:

> In France, the Rooster is seen as a symbol of gallantry. This is
>   because, (supposedly,) if the Rooster finds a food source he will call
>   his hens over to eat before having any himself.

Are there any reliable sources on the true origin of the rooster as a French national symbol?

[image]

Comment: I don't really see the contradiction here. The embassy statement and the wikipedia agree, its a pun on the word gallus. What do you not understand here?

Comment: As Tyler pointed out Wikipedia does not really contradict the embassy's explanation. There's a minor discrepancy over whether `Gallus` means Gaul or an an inhabitant thereof; Wikipedia is correct in that it is the latter. Perhaps the embassy site omitted a plural 's'.

Comment: @TylerDurden The Wikipedia citation claims that it was used by its enemies as a pun and was co-opted for its Christian symbolism. It therefore appears markedly different from the embassy claim.

Comment: Edited to remove the contentious "contradicts" phrase.

Comment: What interests me is the rather coy word *rooster* - uniquely American - for what is a cockerel or cock i.e. a male *gallinaceous* bird.

Comment: @WS2 - If that interests you, I'd encourage checking out [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93025/what-is-the-difference-between-rooster-vs-cock-and-hen-vs-chicken) on the English stack. I assure you that you aren't nearly as amused by our use of that bit of language difference as we are by yours.

Comment: @T.E.D. many decades ago I read a book called *A History of American Prudery* - or something like that. Many words were invented in Victorian America deliberately to avoid anything that might be suggestive of sex. In addition to this people employed vast and capacious table linen that covered the legs of tables (also with chairs) - since the legs could be suggestive of human anatomy. It seems quite astonishing that in 2015 Americans would not call a spade a spade, or a cock a cock!

Comment: @WS2 - We do. We just mean very different things than you when we do so. :-)

Comment: @T.E.D. It must cause hilarity when the James I version of the Bible is read in class. Snigger, snigger!

Comment: @WS2 - Most schools don't do Bible readings. Separation of Church and State and all that.

Comment: @T.E.D. Well Sunday School then!  (Religion, nowadays, isn't much taught in non-church schools in Britain either.)

Comment: We ***still*** don't do source requests. Try the skeptics stack exchange?